# Reachability duplicate symbol

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

Error on link:

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Reachability in /Users/jmf/Documents/iOS Development/jmf_Client/jmf/jmf/ww_libs/libmfcbroem_ios.a(Reachability.o) and /Users/tpf/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/jmf-erlknghfcpoomnfanzovahfacgpv/Build/Intermediates/jmf.build/Debug-iphoneos/jmf.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Reachability.o for architecture armv7
```

If I simply remove the h/m files (and associated import directives) in hopes of just using the Reachability in libmfcbroem_ios.a...the linker throws this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[MKNetworkEngine initWithHostName:customHeaderFields:] in MKNetworkEngine.o
      -[MKNetworkEngine dealloc] in MKNetworkEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I tell the linker to utilize Reachability from the "a" file?

(disclaimer, I'm just getting started with ObjC/iOS)

Thanks for any help...

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this: In your build settings, add a linker flag: -ObjC

Comment: nope, that didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Remove the Reachability.m file, include only the header

Comment: thanks for the reply. i've just tried that and got this link error now: Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_kReachabilityChangedNotification", referenced from:
      -[MKNetworkEngine initWithHostName:customHeaderFields:] in MKNetworkEngine.o
      -[MKNetworkEngine dealloc] in MKNetworkEngine.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)