# ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I am trying to integrate `Zaius iOS SDK` in my app. So when i added the `SDK` and try to run i am getting following error.

```
duplicate symbol _kReachabilityChangedNotification in:

    /Users/mp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hubble-
    dgvyhoahvstjstejqrwunfpqzokr/Build/Products/Debug-
    iphoneos/HubbleIosFramework.framework/HubbleIosFramework(ZReachability.o)

    /Users/mp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Hubble-
    dgvyhoahvstjstejqrwunfpqzokr/Build/Products/Debug-
    iphoneos/HubbleIosFramework.framework/HubbleIosFramework(Reachability.o)

ld: `1 duplicate symbol for architecture arm64`
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Error showing that two duplicate file exit which is `ZReachability.o` and `Reachability.o`.

I have deleted `Reachability class` and try to import `ZReachability.h` but its showing file not exit. May be `SDK` keep ZReachability.h private.

What can i do else to resolve this issue?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11028824/reachability-duplicate-symbol

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451795/duplicate-symbol-linker-error-due-to-libweandsflibrary-aasireachability-o

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I am updating the question. After your suggestion.

Comment: check the updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is **_kReachabilityChangedNotification** ,It is declared with same name in both the files (`ZReachability.h` `Reachability.h.`). This is the reason its shows `duplicate symbol` ensure once, if yes, change the name and run once,surely works.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete it from your folder too. Right click on your project > show in finder > and then search your file name > delete that file.

**It will helps you**

Comment: disant problem not in the entire folder, the questioner copied the class function and added in another place